# Why aren't people answering my questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

About 50% of my questions have had 0 answers on Stack Overflow. Many people are refraining from answering my questions.  Why?

Comment: Where are you getting 50% from?

Comment: I am sorry, But I dont know answer of this question.

Comment: If you count questions that have no upvoted answers, it's around 23.8%.  If you only count questions that have no answers whatsoever, it's around 10.2%, according to my "back of the envelope".

Comment: I have asked many question in stackoverflow but people are not answer to my question so it means people aren't answer the questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mat Actually he has 3 questions, 2 on hold, one open and unanswered, all three unclear and heavily downvoted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they're very poorly asked.

Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't downvote. Actual comment: Shouldn't this answer be counted as a poorly written answer (and a bit rude too). Rude in the sense that it comes from a mod and the recipient is a new user. I totally understand that mod are human and they are tooo busy but still don't write if you don't have time. Keep in mind, this site attracts a lot of new users and there will be people who will never go through the FAQs/Help/Site norms. Thank you.

Comment: We put a ton of effort into writing the page I linked to so that we *wouldn't* have to reiterate it every time this question comes up, @bluemax. I don't see any reason to disrespect the work of the good folk who contributed there by ignoring it in favor of whatever guidance I can pull off the top of my tired brain this evening. (also, I don't care how you voted - vote your conscience, comment as you feel appropriate)

Comment: @bluemax probably the more experienced users know not to make assumptions about who downvoted, or that the commenter must also be the downvoter (or at least I hope so)

Comment: No one is disrespecting the work of the good folks and yourself. Understood your point, however I'll keep my opinion available in the comments. Peace and signing out.

Comment: good, straight answer!

Answer (score 7):

First of all I would suggest that you should go through the Stack Overflow [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically read [about Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and specially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow wants you to post specific questions and it would be good if they contain a bit of source code.

This is not a tutorial site but it is for professional and enthusiast programmers. Your questions are too broad and show no effort from your end. Two of the three questions are one-liner and end with **help me**. The community here wants that you should help yourself first and when you get stuck somewhere then we'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 7):

I'd also add that the way you wrote your questions mean we, the answerers, have to poke and prod and dig and pry in order to get you to give us more details so we can figure out exactly what your problem is. When you include lots of details, it eliminates the need for answerers to leave comments asking *you* questions.

When you take the time to use the space in the question box to include code, what you're trying to do, what you tried, you make it less likely for answerers to have to guess. Imagine you were an answerer, and you tried to answer a question. Let's say you spent 15 to 20 minutes researching and then post a nice answer, only for the asker to come back and say:

> No! alredy i try that solution and it do not work.

That's frustrating for an answerer, and it's frustrating for you, the asker.

In order to maximize everyone's time, we put vague questions on hold to give the authors a chance to edit them and fix them. When you edit, your question will get bumped back to the top of the active page, so users will see it again.

Basically, your question *is* poorly asked. That's a fact, but it doesn't mean you're a bad person or we don't like you. It just means you need some practice in learning the valuable skill of asking good, detailed, technical questions.  I encourage you to pick the question that's most important to you and try editing it, based on the resources others have given you to read.  Also, take a look at the up voted questions on the site to get an idea for what kinds of questions people consider good.

Learning to ask good technical questions is an important skill that will help take you far in your career, as the best communicators tend to be the people who are offered the most opportunities. So use this as a chance to practice and get better. Hope this helps and good luck!